# Trying to validate a piece of HTML

Tags: html

I'm trying to get the following validated, but it fails:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" title="some title">
        <div class="some class">
            <img src="http://somepathtoimage.com" alt="some alt text" />
        </div>
        <h3 class="some class">Some text</h3>
     </a>
</li>
```

Comment: "but they're a bit old" HTML 4 validation hasn't really changed for many years, so why do you think the answers are out of date? What validator are you using? What doctype?

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` tags should never be placed inside `<li>` tags, even worse inside `<a>` tags. Change your `<div>` and `<h3>` to `<span>`

Comment: Wow, thanks for your quick response. With your help I was able to sort it out and successfully validate the HTML. Thanks again!